# Calculating duration between two dates

Tags: views

I am using [Views Calc](https://drupal.org/project/views_calc) for Drupal 7 to calculate duration. I have some questions:

If use Date (Unix timestamp) and subtract end date from start date of my date field with time it gives me seconds then I divide it with 86400 (the seconds in a day) it gives me number of days.

My code in Views Calc:

```
( %field_data_field_we_from_date.field_we_from_date_value2 -
  %field_data_field_we_from_date.field_we_from_date_value ) / 86400
```

which is great;

however:

1. If I use date (not UNIX time stamp) and with no time only year, month, and day then it gives me a number which I don't understand what it represents. If I divide it with 86400, the answer does not look correct. My problem is that we don't need to add time in the field. The end-user doesn't like to see time field with date.
2. When I try to use `NOW()` it give error in Views Calc setting which says `NOW value is not allowed here!` I need `NOW()` - my_date_field to get age and other duration which do not have end date field.
3. `ROUND()` function also doesn't seem to be working.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a little tweak.

After you get the only date in `YYYY-MM-DD` string format, concate `00:00:00` as time to the string. then you can get unix time format by using function [`strtotime()`](https://www.php.net/strtotime) that takes a string date format and returns an integer of time format (unix).

Hopefully this helps you getting the correct duration.

Comment: can i use these functions in views calc?

Comment: I have never used views calc. But as strtotime will return an integer that should be help in calculating time. One more suggestion use time() instead of now() to get current date/time in unix timestamp.

Comment: can't use function with views calc, even now() is not working will try to use computed field.